# How can I approach my company after being made redundant, when contract mentions that they will do their best to find a new employer?

Tags: communication, layoff

My contract mentions that my employer will do their best to find a 'new employer' (in particular their partner companies) if I were to be made redundant.

I have found out today that I have been made redundant, and would love to remain within the current industry.

How can I approach my HR department, and mention that due to me being made redundant, I would appreciate if the company were to assist me in finding a new employer?

NB: Their partner companies are not owned by the same company, they just work together.  One of the partners has a major operation where I am based.

Comment: Why not just ask as you have here? There is no conflict of interest and it is in your contract.

Comment: Which country is this as laws on redundancy vary

Answer (score 3):

> How can I approach my HR department

Ask them if you could get a referral or any other assistance with finding a position at their partner company. They may (probably do) have a direct contact they can give you to get the ball rolling.

Comment: It is a "feel good" perk, really it promises nothing, but they may have contacts or partners that they would refer. Specifically however you should always feel comfortable asking for a referral letter. OP does not state their country but in many places there is a stigma with "quitting" and a referral  or letter stating that there were general lay offs go a long way to getting you considered for a new position.

Comment: @crasic does depend on country in the UK they have a duty of care to actively consider alternate roles

Answer (score 0):

Also – if you are "made redundant" in your present job, *what else* might they be able to find for you to do, that you would enjoy doing (perhaps, even more?).  It never hurts to ask.  You might even manage to wrangle *a promotion* out of it!